# Performance and memory managment impact of using a C# dll with native C++

Tags: c#, c++, performance, memory-management

I want to write a map editor for a game. I intend doing it using C++ and OpenGL. However, the game was written in Unity, so map loading/saving code was written in C#.

Since I worked on a similar project in C# WinForms, I have already written a C# dll that can manage some game generated files, including map files. I now plan to use it to load/save map files in the main C++ program.

What does the C# dll do? (**tl;dr** below the second line)

---

It has a method for loading `Region` into memory, consisting of an array of 1024 `MemoryStreams` that each contain a compressed `Chunk` (about 2kB to 20kB per chunk, mostly around 5kB). It also has a method for requesting a `Chunk` from the `Region`. It decompresses the stream and reads it into a `Chunk` object (which is a complex object with arrays, lists, dictionaries and other custom classes with complexities of their own).

I also have the methods that do the reverse - pack the `Chunk` object into a `MemoryStream`, compress it and add it the `Region` object that has a method which saves it to a file on the disk.

The uncompressed chunk data ranges from 15kB to over 120kB in size, and that's just raw data, not including any object creation related overhead.

In the main program, I'd probably have several thousand of those `Chunks`loaded into memory at once, some maybe briefly to cache some data and be unloaded (to perhaps generate distant terrain), others fully to modify them to the users wishes.

---

**tl;dr** I'd be loading anywhere from a few hundred megabytes up to over a gigabyte of data within a managed c# dll. The data wouldn't be heavily accessed, only changed when user does changes to terrain, which is not that often speaking in terms of time in CPU scale. But as the user moves the map, a lot of chunks might be requested to be loaded/unloaded at a time.

Given that all this is within a managed C# dll, my question is, what happens to memory management and how does that impact performance of the native C++ program? To what extent can I control the memory allocation for the `Region`/`Chunk` objects? How does that impact the speed of execution?

Is it something that can be overlooked/ignored and/or dealt with, or will it pose enough of a problem to justify rewriting the dll in native C++ with a more elaborate memory management scheme?

Comment: If the C# version of the DLL has an interface that you are happy with then I'd guess that your C++ version is going to have a similar interface. If that is the case then why speculate? Just make it work using the C# lib because it is already done. If it turns out to be too slow\hungry then the worst case scenario is that you'll need to write the C++ lib but at least your interface is already defined so you won't need to redesign it and others who already are familiar with the C# lib will be able to quickly understand your C++ lib. If it does work then you've saved a lot of effort.

Comment: who is allocating the memory? although to be honest you'll be fine either way - just expect to get familar with either `unsafe` (keyword) or `Unsafe` ([nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe/)),